# Error when trying to execute PHPUnit Test in Symfony 2.8

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit, web-crawler

I'm trying to execute a simple test with PHPUnit on Symfony 2.8 application.
This is the test:

```
public function testCreateContact(){
        $client= static::createClient();
        $client->followRedirects();
        $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/contact_create');
        $link = $crawler->filter('a:contains("Cancel")')->link();
        $crawlerLink = $client->click($link);

    }
```

And the TWIG file:

```html
{% extends '::layout.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}MaestroBundle:Contacto:alta{% endblock %}

{% block body %}

<h1>New Contacto</h1>
<div class="form_error"></div>
<div id="form_body">
    <form id="createForm" method="POST" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
            {{ form_widget(formulario) }}
            <input type="submit" value="create"/>
        </form>
            <a id="cancel" name="cancel" href="{{ path('contact_show') }}">Cancel</a>

</div>
{% endblock %}
```

When I execute this test, I get the following error:

> There was 1 error:
>
> 1)
>   SisEvo\MaestroBundle\Tests\Controller\ContactoControllerTest::testCrearContacto
>   InvalidArgumentException: The current node list is empty.
>
> /var/www/html/evoIsaac/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DomCrawler/Crawler.php:706
>   /var/www/html/evoIsaac/src/SisEvo/MaestroBundle/Tests/Controller/ContactoControllerTest.php:24
>
> FAILURES! Tests: 2, Assertions: 1, Errors: 1.

This is the line number 24: 
$link = $crawler->filter('a:contains("Cancel")')->link();

Furthermore, I tried to check the $crawler content with var_dump, and this is the result:

> The file "/var/www/html/evoIsaac/app/config/routing.yml" does not
>   contain valid YAML in /var/www/html/evoIsaac/app/config/routing.yml
>   (which is being imported from
>   "/var/www/html/evoIsaac/app/config/routing_dev.yml"). (500 Internal
>   Server Error)

PHPUnit version: 5.3.2
PHP Version: 5.6.18
Symfony version: 2.8.4
OS: Fedora 23

Can someone help me?

**EDIT**

I tried to check my YAML file, and I get this error:

> ERROR:
>
> while scanning for the next token found character '@' that cannot
>   start any token   in "", line 22, column 15:
>           resource: @MaestroBundle/Controller/
>                     ^

This is my YAML file:

```
cys:
    resource: "@CysBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /

homepage:
    path: /
    defaults:
        _controller: FrameworkBundle:Template:template
        template:    'default/login.html.twig'


contrato_evolutia:
    resource: "@ContratoEvolutiaBundle/Controller/"
    type: annotation

api_maestro:
    resource: "@ApiBundle/Controller/Maestro/"
    type:     annotation

maestro:
    resource: @MaestroBundle/Controller/
    type:     annotation

default:
    resource: @DefaultBundle/Controller/
    type:     annotation


fos_js_routing:
    resource: "@FOSJsRoutingBundle/Resources/config/routing/routing.xml"
```

I also tried to check the client response with:

```
$this->assertTrue($client->getResponse()->isSuccessful());
```

But PHPUnit shows this error:

> Failed asserting that false is true

Hope that someone can help me.

Comment: As stated in the error message, you have an error in `app/config/routing.yml`. You can check it with an online YAML validator: http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/

Comment: Only as a note, before checking other stuff verify that the client request go well as example `$this->assertTrue($client->getResponse()->isSuccessful());`

Comment: Thank you, I tried your solutions, and edited the question with the results.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved the problem!!
Thank you @A.L and @Matteo for your comments; the problem was that I have no "" in the YAML before the @Bundle, now it's working!

My final version of YAML file is:

```
 cys:
    resource: "@CysBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /

homepage:
    path: /
    defaults:
        _controller: FrameworkBundle:Template:template
        template:    'default/login.html.twig'


contrato_evolutia:
    resource: "@ContratoEvolutiaBundle/Controller/"
    type: annotation

api_maestro:
    resource: "@ApiBundle/Controller/Maestro/"
    type:     annotation

maestro:
    resource: "@MaestroBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation

default:
    resource: "@DefaultBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation


fos_js_routing:
    resource: "@FOSJsRoutingBundle/Resources/config/routing/routing.xml"
```

Thank you very much!
Isaac.